# How to update all matching query on Firebase/Cloud DataStore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update all records matching a query in Fire/DataStore, how do I do it?

The SQL equivalent will look like

```
UPDATE transactions SET category = X WHERE category = Y
```

Seems like to do this I will have to query all records matching `category = Y` then for each do a `set()`?

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on thgis? I noticed you never got back to me on the answer below. Did that not address your question?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore (like most NoSQL databases) does not support sending update queries directly to the database.

To update documents matching a query, you will indeed first need to execute that query and then update each document.

Comment: @JiewMeng: if my answer does not address you question, can you let me know what more you are looking for?